# Best practice to change class on <li> and its child <a> upon click

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a `<li>` element and I'm changing the css class of the `<li>` element upon click, using the `ng-click` (setting its controller highlighted holder variable) and `ng-class` (checking whether the `<li>` is highlighted in the controller and applying two types of classes for the true/false cases).

however I also need to change the class of the `<a>` which is a sub-element of the `<li>` based on the highlighting flag as I need a different text color.

do I create two `ng-class` tags for the `<li>` and the `<a>` inside of it and repeat the condition? or is there a better way?

I mean, it seems excessive to do this:

```
<li ng-click="navCtrl.setNav(1)" ng-class="{ 'nav_items_selected': navCtrl.isNavPage(1) , 'nav_items': !navCtrl.isNavPage(1) }"><a ng-class="{ 'nav_selected_a': navCtrl.isNavPage(1) , 'nav_a': !navCtrl.isNavPage(1) }" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Comment: how about adding javascript event onlick to the A href ?

Comment: will this and the ng-click live in peace?

Comment: No, they won't. Don't do it. Even if it worked, still don't do it. That's just messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directive for changing the class of li and child a. I think its much better to use directive for handling DOM stuffs. it is also reusable for your future codes. documentation for directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

you can do something like this:

```
app.directive('changeClass', ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function(event) {
        var aChild = elem.children('a');

        if(!elem.hasClass('active-li')){
          elem.addClass('active-li');
          aChild.addClass('active-link');          
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('active-li');
          aChild.removeClass('active-link');
        }

      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

html

```
<li change-class class="">
  <a href="#" class="">
     Dashboard
  </a>
</li>
```

working demo here  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EYZtBSa6cD3VCMHBBSQg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably target your `<a>` in css without applying another class to it, since you've already done that to its `<li>` ancestor.

https://jsfiddle.net/tvbL877w/

Let's say you've got this css code:

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.selected .some-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

and your html is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="{selected: myBoolean}">
    Let's get some <a href="#" class="some-child" ng-click="myBoolean = !myBoolean" >CAKES!!!</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```